# MySql: How to set my.cnf to accept both uppercase and lowercase tables

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, weblogic, plesk

How to setup mysql my.cnf to accept both uppercase and lowercase tables.

Environment:
Os: Ubuntu 14.04 TLS
Mysql Server:
App Server: WLServer 12.2.1  (Only uppercase tables are accepted)
Plesk: 12.0.8  (Only lowercase tables are accepted)

I try

```
lower_case_table_names=2 #(default value '0')
```

Error message:

```
database.table   doesn't exist
```

if i use

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

The WLserver work fine but my Wiki, plesk .... have problems

How could i  deal with this issue?

Comment: Why do you need case-insensitivity? See this explanation of which settings are valid on which operating systems due to the OS case-sensitivity. : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: my case is not only os matter. WLServer accept only uppercase tables

Comment: Unfortunately, as explained, MySQL is constrained by the case-sensitivity of the operating system. It can use case-sensitive or lower case only on unix based OS's. If WLServer only accepts uppercase table names, then would it be an option to use upper-case tables in MySQL?